# How can we add child to a custom control deriving from Panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm making a custom control deriving from StackPanel. It is a row of a crossword puzzle. At first, I added the cells manually in XAML and the cells show normally, but when I add it in the control's code's constructor, they're gone. How can I solve this problem?

I tried changing the children adding part to `InternalChildren.Add()`, `Children.Add()`, `AddVisualChild()` but none of those work.

Row's code:

```cs
public class Row : StackPanel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowAnswerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RowAnswer", typeof(string), typeof(Row), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string RowAnswer
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RowAnswerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowAnswerProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObstacleRow()
    {
        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        Children.Clear();
        string answerWithoutSpace = RowAnswer.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();
        for (int i = 0; i < answerWithoutSpace.Length; i++)
            AddLogicalChild(new Cell { CellChar = answerWithoutSpace[i], Width = 32, Height = 32, Margin = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 0) });
    }
}
```

Comment: in the constructor RowAnswer is empty, so you don't have any child items. i don't think that deriving from StackPanel is optimal solution. ItemsControl can produce required layout

Comment: I set the RowAnswer in XAML.

Comment: but children are not updated. they are only generated in ctor. what about  ItemsControl part?

Comment: Then how do I update children? I don't like ItemsControl and UpdateLayout doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to use `Panel.Children.Add`. As ASh has mentioned you should check the value of `RowAnswer` when you are inside the constructor. It appears to be empty as it might not be loaded at this point..

Comment: I also agree that a `StackPanel` is the wrong choice. A `Grid` or even `DataGrid` with the dimension of the complete puzzle would be the better option I think. Then fill the cells with letters and draw the border of the used cell.

Comment: In fact `RowAnswer` _must_ be empty. It is a `DependencyProperty` of `ObstacleRow` and is initialized with the default value `""`. When inside the constructor the property is not set yet. You must subscribe to the `Loaded` event. This is where the bindings and their values are available and therefore the property `RowAnswer` is set.

Comment: @BionicCode, "You must subscribe to the Loaded event' - very wrong. DP might change any time after loading. To react to value changes, DP registration has PropertyChangedCallback

Comment: @ASh Yes, right. When you want to make it dynamic, then you are right. But for the construction, the earliest moment is when the control is loaded. That's what I am saying.

Comment: @TrietVoNguyenMinh, I *like* ItemsControl because it is as simple as `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source='RowAnswer'}"/>`. Implementing custom Panel correctly will take efforts

Comment: I don't know how to use Panel.Children.Add. It throws "An object reference is required..."

Comment: The DP is static so no worries :D Thank you for all your help :D